# Virtocommerce deploy on domain and hosting service provider

Tags: virtocommerce

In Virtocommerce document I can deploy it on Azure or my local PC. Is it possible that I can also deploy it on domain and hosting service provider like godaddy or other domain and hosting service provider?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but in this case your deployment scenario will be a same as [deploy VC to dedicated server](http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Deploy+web+applications+to+dedicated+server)